# when I create super user for custom user model, its dont provide me username, firstname, lastname filed then its show error

Tags: django, django-models, django-custom-user, django-custom-manager

when I create super user for custom user  model, its dont provide me username, firstname, lastname filed then its show this error:
MyAccountManager.create_superuser() missing 3 required positional arguments: 'first_name', 'last_name', and 'username'

Here My Code:

```
class MyAccountManager(BaseUserManager):
   def create_user(self,first_name,last_name, username, email, password=None):
      email = self.normalize_email(email)
      if email is None:
         raise ValueError('User Must have a email')
    
      first_name = first_name.title()
      last_name = last_name.title()
      username = username.title()

      user = self.model(
        email=email,
        first_name= first_name,
        last_name=last_name,
        username=username
        

    )
      user.set_password(password)
      user.save(using = self._db)
      return user

     def create_superuser(self, email,first_name,last_name, username, password=None):
      user = self.create_user(email=email, password=password,first_name= first_name,
        last_name=last_name,
        username=username),
      user.is_staff = True
  
      user.save(using = self._db)


 class Account(AbstractBaseUser):
  first_name = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)
  last_name = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)
  username = models.CharField(
    max_length=50, default='test', unique=True, blank=True, null=True)
  email = models.EmailField(max_length=100, unique=True)
  phone_number = models.CharField(max_length=50)

# required
 date_joined = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
 last_login = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

 is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)
 is_active = models.BooleanField(default=False)

 objects = MyAccountManager()

 USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
 REQUIRED_FIELD = ['username', 'first_name','last_name']
```

Comment: I think, you don't supplied the username, firstname, lastname while create superuser

Comment: in console, there are no field for send username, firstname,lastname

Answer (score 0):

You can write your create_superuser method like this:

```
class MyAccountManager(BaseUserManager):

    def create_superuser(self, email, password, **extra_fields):
        """
        Create and save a SuperUser with the given email and password.
        """
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_staff', True)
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_superuser', True)
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_active', True)

        if extra_fields.get('is_staff') is not True:
            raise ValueError(_('Superuser must have is_staff=True.'))
        if extra_fields.get('is_superuser') is not True:
            raise ValueError(_('Superuser must have is_superuser=True.'))
        return self.create_user(email, password, **extra_fields)
```

Answer (score 0):

It's working:

```
class MyAccountManager(BaseUserManager):
   def create_user(self, email, password=None, **extra_fields):
      email = self.normalize_email(email)
      if email is None:
         raise ValueError('User Must have a email')

    # first_name = first_name.title()
    # last_name = last_name.title()
    # username = username.title()

     user = self.model(
        email=email,
        # first_name=first_name,
        # last_name=last_name,
        # username=username,
        **extra_fields


    )
     user.set_password(password)
     user.save(using=self._db)
     return user

  def create_superuser(self, email, password, **extra_fields):
    """
    Create and save a SuperUser with the given email and password.
    """
    extra_fields.setdefault('is_staff', True)
    extra_fields.setdefault('is_admin', True)
    extra_fields.setdefault('is_active', True)

    if extra_fields.get('is_staff') is not True:
        raise ValueError(('Superuser must have is_staff=True.'))
    # if extra_fields.get('is_superuser') is not True:
    #     raise ValueError(('Superuser must have is_superuser=True.'))
    return self.create_user(email=email, password=password,**extra_fields)


class Account(AbstractBaseUser):
  first_name = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)
  last_name = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)
  username = models.CharField(
    max_length=50, unique=True, blank=True, null=True)
  email = models.EmailField(max_length=100, unique=True)
  phone_number = models.CharField(max_length=50)

  # required
  date_joined = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
  last_login = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

  is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)
  is_active = models.BooleanField(default=False)
  is_admin = models.BooleanField(default=False)

  objects = MyAccountManager()

  USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
  REQUIRED_FIELD = ['username', 'first_name', 'last_name']

  def __str__(self):
     return self.email

  def has_perm(self,perm, obj=None ):
     return self.is_admin

  def has_module_perms(self, add_label):
     return True
```